# Ubuntu 17.10., Eclipse Oxygen and Eclipse RCP App Developement

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, swt

I recently moved from Ubuntu 14.10/ Eclipse Mars to Ubuntu 17.10/ Eclipse Oxygen. I am developing an Eclipse RCP application.

With the new setup, the application fails to start:

```
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
```

I already tried starting Eclipse like

```
export GDK_BACKEND=x11
./eclipse &
```

And give the app another startup parameter:

[image]

I am not sure if that does have any effect, though.

Also I am not sure, if that is really a Wayland issue.

My Eclipse version:

[image]

**Solution:**

Switching to GTK2 solved the problem. Don't understand why, because this should only affect Eclipse itself, not the RCP app I am starting?

eclipse.ini:

```
[..]
--launcher.GTK_version
2
[..]
```

Comment: Possibly bug [497705](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497705) marked as fixed in 4.7.1 and later (Oxygen.1)

Comment: I am running Oxygen.2, as far as I can tell. See updated question.

Comment: Same here: Photon Release 4.8.0, Ubuntu 18.04LTS. GTK_version solved it too, thx!